# VBA UsedRange Sum

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and I am struggling to understand some key things.

Why cannot I calculate the sum of UsedRange in A1 by doing the following?

```
Sub UsedR_S

Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sum

End sub
```

Is it because the function sum only works if you put data after it rather than before it?

Comment: You can use `Application.Sum(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)` or `WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)`.

Comment: `UsedRange` is a `Range`. A `Range` object has no `.Sum` method.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the property/method available to the object, you should always consult the documentation first ([Range object documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))), click the object in VBE then press F1 usually will open the documentation page for you to read. (e.g. in the line `Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sum`, click the word `UsedRange` then press F1 will open up the `UsedRange` property documentation which you will see that it's actually a `Range` object.)

Comment: Thank you very much. So the way to know the properties and methods that range can take are listed here right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object) Since "sum" is not there, it means it cannot be a method/property for "range"? Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Exactly. You can also see them for all objects in the VBE, best by using a variable e.g. `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1")`. Now when you write in the next line `rg.` (note the dot), VBA's intellisense will appear showing a list of all the methods and properties. Try it yourself.